# About ReadProcessMemory Speed

Tags: vb.net, api

```
    Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "ReadProcessMemory" (ByVal hProcess As Int32, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Int32, ByRef lpBuffer As Int32, ByVal nSize As` Int32, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Int32) As Int32   
Sub test()        
Dim buffer(4096) As Int32
             For i As Long = &H2A000000 To &H3A000000
                            ReadProcessMemory(hwnd, i, buffer, buffer.length, 0)
                    Next
End Sub
Error   1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
```

this code get me over 1 minute to complete it .
my teacher told me "It's like you're coding on someone computer with teamviewer or you're copy code to your computer and code on it , which is faster".
clearly the second one , he told me that my code are like the 1st.
someone tell me how to speed it up? .
thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your buffer size **larger** so you copy more at once, and then iterate over your local copy of the data, which should go much faster.

You'll have to experiment to see what the ideal size buffer is...I have no idea what that might be.

Try this for your API declaration:

```
Public Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "KERNEL32" Alias "ReadProcessMemory" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Int32, _
     ByVal BaseAddress As Int32, _
     ByVal BUFFER As Byte(), _
     ByVal Size As Int32, _
     Optional ByRef SizeReturned As Int32 = Nothing) As Boolean
```

Then you can call it using something like:

```
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
    For i As Long = &H2A000000 To &H3A000000
        ReadProcessMemory(hwnd, i, buffer, buffer.Length)
    Next
```

Comment: Dim buffer(10000000) As Int32
ReadProcessMemory(hwnd, i,buffer, 10000000, 0) 
Error :(

Comment: That's a **huge** buffer.  Try something smaller like 4096.

Comment: Also, instead of manually typing in the size of the buffer to the 4th parameter or ReadProcessMemory(), use `buffer.Length` instead.

Comment: Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
i'm getting this error on buffer
ReadProcessMemory(hwnd, i, buffer, buffer.Length, 0)
what should i do now?

Comment: **Edit** your initial post with your current code so we can see it better.  Show us the declaration, loop, and call.

Comment: Was it faster with a larger buffer?